# Can you "force" `scipy.stats.norm.rvs` to output positive values?

Tags: numpy, random, scipy, statistics, distribution

This may be a naive question but I couldn't find any posts about it so I thought it may be useful to ask. I found a distribution that may fit my data well but all of my data points are positive in real life (- ones are impossible).

**Is there a way to force `.rvs` to output only positive values?**

I thought of some ways but they seem pretty CPU intensive like making way more values than I would need and then doing a boolean mask for all the values that are positive and `np.random.choice` from those.  **Is there a better way?**

I didn't see anything about it in the docs :/ about this:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html

My phrases to find this didn't yield any results:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=force+scipy+rvs+positive and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scipy+rvs+positive

```
params = (0.00169906712999, 0.00191866845411)
np.random.seed(0)
stats.norm.rvs(*params, size=10)
array([ 0.0050837 ,  0.00246684,  0.00357694,  0.0059986 ,  0.00528229,
       -0.00017601,  0.00352197,  0.00140866,  0.00150102,  0.00248687])
```

Comment: As long as the standard deviation (second paramater, `scale`) is greater than the mean (first parameter, `loc`), `.rvs()` will always have a chance of putting out negative numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be looking for [truncnorm](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html#scipy.stats.truncnorm): a truncated normal continuous random variable.

For example, try:

```
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> params = (0.00169906712999, 0.00191866845411)
>>> params[0] + stats.truncnorm.rvs(-params[0]/params[1], np.infty, size=10, scale=params[1])
array([ 0.00235414,  0.00310856,  0.00258259,  0.00233789,  0.00185298,
        0.00277454,  0.00190764,  0.00429671,  0.00532165,  0.00169576])
```

The first two arguments to `stats.truncnorm.rvs` are the truncation limits.  Because these are computed for the *normal* distribution (mean=0 std dev=1), we have to scale the parameters appropriately.

We use `np.infty` for the upper limit on the range because we don't want any truncation on the upper side.

#### Verifying that none of the output is negative

Let's look at the minimum and maximum of the output over 100,000 samples:

```
>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> np.min(params[0] + stats.truncnorm.rvs(-params[0]/params[1], np.infty, size=100000, scale=params[1]))
1.9136656654716172e-08
>>> np.max(params[0] + stats.truncnorm.rvs(-params[0]/params[1], np.infty, size=10000, scale=params[1]))
0.0088294835649150548
```

As you can see, the minimum never goes negative.  The maximum is a few std dev above the mean.

Comment: Or halfnorm, in this specific case

Comment: Is there any way to apply this generally to all distributions? This definitely works for normal. Thanks for the details on the answer.  I would have been confused implementing it w/o the examples!

Comment: @ev-br It would be half-norm if the OP was using a distribution with mean=0.  Looking at the details shown in the question, though, the mean is `params[0]` which is non-zero.

Comment: @O.rka [scipy.stats](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/stats.html) offers a couple other truncated distributions, such as truncated exponential and truncated Gumbel.  For other distributions, one may have to result to brute force: generate samples, discard ones outside of the range, and repeat until enough samples have been generated.

Comment: @John1024 halfnorm with loc=params[0]

Comment: @ev-br That is interesting.  Thanks for that info.  I tested it and all the numbers that it returns are greater than `params[0]`.   My interpretation of the OP's question, though, is that he wants to numbers greater than zero whether they are less than `params[0]` or not.  But, if he did want a normal distribution _truncated at the mean_, then `halfnorm` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Depends how true to the distribution you want to stay.  If you only want positive values, it's not really a normal distribution since you'll never get negative values.

However, you could force positive values with `abs(output)` where output is your `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I will try this for non-normal distributions.  I was also thinking about maybe just masking all the negative values w/ a highpass filter.  The dataset I was trying to apply it to has a range from 0 - 1 and it's pretty sparse.

Comment: The problem with `abs()` is you're effectively folding the normal distribution back on itself which causes it to deviate from the gaussian shape. You end up sampling from a distribution with a peak at the desired mean and a secondary peak rising at zero.